# Create object with number of fields based upon requirement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have a situation:

Lets say I have a `User` class
which looks like

```
public class User
{
   public IEnumerable<ConnectionService> ConnectionServices {get;set}
}

public class ConnectionService
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string ConnectionName {get;set;}
  public string Username {get;set;}
  public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

Here user can have multiple ConnectionService. Right now a connectionservice has Username and password, so just two fields(excluding Id and ConnectionName). What if some connectionservice needs 20 fields? I can add those fields in ConnectionService class but each time a connectionservice instance will be created there will be fields that are not needed for that particular service. How do I solve this?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Should it maybe have a `Dictionary<string,object>` instead of dedicated Properties (what you've shown, not Fields)? Also, I've picked `object` to accommodate all possible types rather than forcing them all to be `int` (an unusual choice for usernames and passwords)

Comment: sorry int was type mistake

Comment: Have you considered to create a `IConnectionService` and `public IEnumerable<IConnectionService> ConnectionServices {get;set}`? This would be a typical polymorphic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subclass ConnectionService (or just declare an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)) and create particular services with their specific attributes; then, you can use any of these wherever a ConnectionService is needed, like in a user. This is called [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)